# What is the meaning "It is permitted us to know ..."

Tags: meaning, archaicisms, indirect-objects

I saw a sentence

> It is permitted us to know respecting the signs, which are spoken by the prophets, for they foretold signs by which the consummation of the times is to be expected by us from day to day, and to be feared.

Perhaps it is archaic English? I just want to know the meaning "It is permitted us to know ...". Could you give me a modern English equivalent?

Comment: It is permitted _to_ us to know ... sounds slightly less strange to my ears. 'We are allowed to know ...'. This presumes some super-agent doing the 'allowing'.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that it is archaic. It's a fairly literal translation of Latin<sup>1</sup> written by [Lactantius](http://st-takla.org/books/en/ecf/007/0070189.html), a "pre-Nicene Father of the Church" — he lived [c.250–c.325](http://earlychurch.org.uk/lactantius.php). The translation [appears to have been made by Rev Dr William Fletcher](http://st-takla.org/books/en/ecf/007/0070002.html), probably in the nineteenth century.

The use of *permit* to take a direct object in **that passive-voice sentence** is unusual, but consider "He permitted us to know something". That meaning is clear: we are allowed to know something (by "him", whoever that refers to).

The use of the passive voice removes a concrete subject; there is no mention of who is doing the permitting. It would be more normal now to write "We are permitted to know," where the subject of the passive-voice sentence is the object of the verb, "permit us". But "It is permitted us" serves the same purpose: who or what is actually "permitting us" is not stated; merely that we are permitted to know it.

I've found [the original Latin](http://www.documentacatholicaomnia.eu/04z/z_0240-0320__Lactantius__Divinarum_Institutionum_Liber_VII__MLT.pdf.html), and *permit us* doesn't appear in that form. *Licet noscere* means "it is permitted to recognise". The translator wanted to retain the "It is permitted" passive form and not alter that to "We are permitted". Perhaps *nos* in *noscere* may mean a Latin etymology from "be to us" which would justify a translation of "it is permitted us to know" by analogy with "He permitted us" as I mentioned above.

---

1. De signis quae praedicta sunt a prophetis, licet noscere; predixerunt enim signa, quibus consummatio temporum, et expectanda sit nobis in singulos dies, et timenda.

Comment: Thanks. I also found another sentence similarly awkward. This time the sentence happens in 3 MODERN translations of the Bible, as “... your sins are forgiven you.” (Luke 5:23) So the 2 awkward sentences are—
It is permitted us ….  
… your sins are forgiven you. 
So the “us” and “you” are superfluous in modern English. Am I correct? If I am correct, I just don’t understand why the sentence happens in 3 MODERN versions. Thanks to anyone who helps in advance.

Comment: The same thing probably applies: the desire to produce an accurate translation where the indirect object pronoun exists in the original in some form.